# "A" and "CNAME" record not working for www using Cloud DNS

Tags: web, google-cloud-platform, dns, cloud, google-cloud-dns

I use Cloud DNS to host my website: https://ewerton.com.br

Today, I saw that when I try to access my website using "http(s)://www. [...]", it is unreachable.

I tried to search for similar questions, but I have the records set up as you can see below, and I've already tried to change that last entry to a CNAME, but to no avail.

[Cloud DNS records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGrS8.png)

Comment: What is the status of your SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I have given a look to your website and it seems that now it is working as expected. I believe the issue you faced is that sometimes it take up to 72 hours for the name server to be propagated, as mentioned in the GCP public documentation:

[Note: The name server update can take from 48 to 72 hours to propagate](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial#update-nameservers)

The same will happen every time you change the name server configuration. Let me know if you have any additional question.

Comment: There is no DNS propagation.

Comment: Thanks, guys :).Didn't know about that. Sorry for the silly question.